# How to find the maximum difference between numbers in VBA with multiple sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets

Sheet1:

```
ID  Number  
A    1
B    2 
C    3
```

Sheet2:

```
ID  Number  
B    8
A    10 
D    5
```

I want to write a function in VBA that can match the IDs and find the difference between the numbers 
For example the function will spit out for the difference depending on each ID, such that A = 9, B = 6.

Then I want to find the maximum difference. So in this case the maximum difference will be for A = 9.

Finally, I want a pop up message box that says (in this example) "largest difference was 9 in A"

This is my first time trying to use VBA, and I tried to look up many examples and videos, but I am lost. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do you need VBA? You could use a VLOOKUP to check. Assuming the columns are A and B for `ID` and `Number`. Put this in, say `Sheet1!C2`: `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)-$B2`

Comment: I need it so that it can also be adaptable to changes, so that if I input another column D with its numbers in each of the sheets, the function can find the maximum difference as well. And I also need to use VBA. Thank you for your help! (:

Comment: I'd expand your question then. As it stands it's a simple `VLOOKUP()` solution, but with what you're trying to do it would be a little more nuanced.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I really don't know what I am doing, but I have tried to make an if else statement such that if the `ID` values in each of the sheets match, then find at the value in `Number` column that corresponds to the ID and minus those values. However I do not know how to compute the "then" portion. So I am in a little bit of the hiccup. Any ideas?

Comment: *(is it Sunday again already?!)*  I assume this is an assignment, that **has to be** done in VBA?  Because if not, a [**pivot table**](https://www.techbout.com/pivot-table-from-multiple-worksheets-4974/) would be far more effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a starting point for you.

1) If you want to know the max difference between the numbers, you may use the following User Defined Function which you can either use in another macro or on the sheet itself as shown in the image

```
Function MaxDifference(ByVal Rng1 As Range, ByVal Rng2 As Range) As Variant
Dim x, y
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim max

x = Rng1.Value
y = Rng2.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If x(i, 1) = y(j, 1) Then
            If Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2)) > max Then
                max = Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2))
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

MaxDifference = max
End Function
```

2) If you also want to know which ID has the max difference, you may try the following UDF.

```
Function MaxDifferenceIDNumber(ByVal Rng1 As Range, ByVal Rng2 As Range, IdOrNumber As String) As Variant
Dim x, y
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim max
Dim ID As String
x = Rng1.Value
y = Rng2.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If x(i, 1) = y(j, 1) Then
            If Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2)) > max Then
                max = Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2))
                ID = x(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If LCase(IdOrNumber) = "id" Then
    MaxDifferenceIDNumber = ID
ElseIf LCase(IdOrNumber) = "number" Then
    MaxDifferenceIDNumber = max
End If
End Function
```

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

You may have the following UDF and the macro on a Standard Module. Assign the macro `LargestIDNumber` to a button which when clicked will display a message as per your requirement.

Don't forget to delete the existing UDF from the module before placing the following UDF.

**UDF:**

```
Function MaxDifferenceIDNumber(ByVal Rng1 As Range, ByVal Rng2 As Range) As Variant
Dim x, y
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim max
Dim ID As String
x = Rng1.Value
y = Rng2.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If x(i, 1) = y(j, 1) Then
            If Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2)) > max Then
                max = Abs(x(i, 2) - y(j, 2))
                ID = x(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

MaxDifferenceIDNumber = "The Largest difference value was " & max & " for " & ID

End Function
```

**Code for button:**

```
Sub LargestIDNumber()
    MsgBox MaxDifferenceIDNumber(Sheet1.Range("A2:B4"), Sheet2.Range("A2:B4"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Could this be translated into a Message box such that if I pressed a button the msgbox = "largest difference value was "x" for "id" ? Sorry I should have said thatI wanted also wanted msg box pop up...But THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU HELPED ME OUT ALOT

Comment: You're welcome! I have edited the answer and added the tweaked UDF. I have also added a code called `LargestIDNumber` which you can assign to a button.

Comment: Also, the ID's might not be in the corresponding order as the other sheet, is there anyway the code can be modified for that? I have edited my question if you don't understand what I mean. Again, Thank you so much

Comment: Ask question only after trying the solution first. The sequence of IDs doesn't matter i.e both the sheets may have IDs in different order. The code will find the ID for max difference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand the code. Thank you for all of your help